# Logstash(6.5.4) elasticsearch output

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

My filebeat is on two servers. let's say app1 and app2

My logs are in the format

```
jobID status data
```

Example:
app1 log

```
5hgsxyt3838 SCHEDULED data
```

app2 log

```
5hgsxyt3838 COMPLETE data
```

Here both these logs have the same jobID.
I am using this jobID as the document _id on elasticsearch

```
elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
            index => "import-export-logger-%{index-name}"
            document_id => "%{jobID}"
        }
```

Now I want my final status in elasticsearch as COMPLETE but sometimes there is a high load on app1 so app2 logs are processed first then app1.
So the final status becomes SCHEDULED

Is there a way to prevent this from happening i.e I want my document to be updated only when the status is not COMPLETE?
When the status is COMPLETE document must not update itself

Comment: On thing you could do is, on `COMPLETE` you say it is an upsert, if the doc exists you update it, if it does not you create it. And on `SCHEDULE` you create, which will create a document if it does not exist but will fail if it **does** exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a huge fan of overwriting events like this (It would be better to just record all the events and then filter in your queries).

But if you want to go that path anyways you can do this:

```
output {
    if [status] == "COMPLETE" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
            index => "import-export-logger-%{index-name}"
            document_id => "%{jobID}"
            action => "update"
            doc_as_upsert => true
        }
    }
    else {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
            index => "import-export-logger-%{index-name}"
            document_id => "%{jobID}"
            action => "create"
        }
    }
}
```

So if status is scheduled will create the document if doesnt already exists, complete will update or create.

Comment: Hi, @llermaly ... Thanks for the reply. Let's say my logs in app1 is `5hgsxyt3838 SCHEDULED data` and on app2 are printed in order `5hgsxyt3838 RUNNING data` `5hgsxyt3838 RUNNING data` `5hgsxyt3838 COMPLETE data`. The purpose of using document_id field in logstash was to track the real-time status of a job. If I use the method you suggested I will have a duplicate entry in my elasticsearch for a jobID. Can you tell me a way to check if there exists a document in elasticsearch with _id as jobID and its status is COMPLETE then I should be able to reject any other event for that jobID

Comment: The answer will do that. You can not create 2 documents with the same id , so if it is complete you will create if does not exist , update if it exist and reject any document with the same id adterwards

Comment: You can invert the if logic and say if complete update , else create

Comment: Will this configuration result in an increased load on logstash and elasticsearch?